# How to resolve the "EBADENGINE Unsupported engine" warning when installing a package with npm?

Tags: reactjs, mern

I want to install qr scanner for npm. how it fix this warning or i need match qr scanner for match my npm version
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkrE3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y80G8.png)

Comment: Please read [the engines section in the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#engines).